# MATLAB - accessing python lists and tuples

Tags: matlab

I have a python function, `Foo`, which returns a tuple of 3 lists. Each list contains points I would like to manipulate and plot in matlab. Current I can retrieve my data with

```
data = py.Foo.main(args)
```

Plotting the output proved difficult. Matlab sees "data" as a python object. I was previously in a rush and my quick work around was

```
function [r] = convertToVector(c)
%make sure everything is numeric so I can plot it
r = [];
for i = 1:length(c)
    if isnumeric(c{i})
        r = [r c{i}];
    end
end

filler = data.cell()
a = convertToVector(filler{1}.cell())
b = convertToVector(filler{1}.cell())
c = convertToVector(filler{1}.cell())
```

This works okay but for `c` I have something like

```
filler.cell{3}.cell = [0] [-1] [-1] [-1] [0.22] [0.13] [0.08]
```

When I run `convertToVector` everything is either 0 or -1. I have no idea what is going on. If I play around in the console I can get something like

```
r = [];
z = filler.cell{3}.cell;
r = [r z{1}]      >>> r = 0
r = [r z{2}]      >>> r = 0 -1
r = [r z{5}]      >>> r = 0 -1 0
```

Why is this happening? If I replace `z{1} z{2} z{5}` with `0 -1 0.22` respectively, I get the results I would expect: `r = 0 -1 0.22`. I don't use matlab regularly and I have no idea what may cause this. I was trying to plug the results of an analysis done in python into a pre-existing matlab gui, otherwise I would avoid interfacing the two as such.

Edit: Under further inspection utilizing `whos r` the class is `int64` when adding `z{1} to z{4}` first and `double` when adding `z{5}` first. The class then changes from `double` to `int64` if I add `z{1} to z{4}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your edit, it seems the problem is that the initial integers in each cell (which are stored as `int`s or maybe `numpy.uint64` types in python) are not automatically cast to `double`, and this seems reasonable. If you concatenate `double`s to the `uint64` array, the `double`s will be cast to `uint64` and not the other way around. This is only surprising since MATLAB very heavily defaults to using `double`s whenever possible, so you might not expect this.

Simple python-free demonstration:

```
a = uint64([3, 4, 5]);
b = [a, 6];
c = [b, 7.3];
```

after this all three arrays will have `uint64` class. Well, the example is a bit redundant, since `class(6)` is `double`, so if there was any typecasting, it would've already happened for `b`.

The solution is simple: explicitly cast to `double` in your function,

```
function [r] = convertToVector(c)
%make sure everything is numeric so I can plot it
r = [];
for i = 1:length(c)
    if isnumeric(c{i})
        r = [r double(c{i})];  %// only change here
    end
end
```